# Getting duplication of row after using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I want to connect 3 tables in one. But when i do so I got duplication of some columns.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pl.projectNo, pl.proc_leader, pc.proc_checker, ps.proc_staff FROM proc_leader pl
LEFT JOIN proc_checker pc ON pl.projectNo=pc.projectNo
LEFT JOIN proc_staff ps ON pl.projectNo=ps.projectNo
WHERE pl.projectNO="17010002" ORDER BY pl.projectNo
```

What I got from my query is:

```
| projectNo | proc_leader | proc_checker | proc_staff | 
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| 170002    | BARIKAN     |    BENNY     |   BOBBY    |
| 170002    | BARIKAN     |    BENNY     |   CHRIS    |
```

So the problem is I have only one BARIKAN and BENNY but it duplicates names. What I need is to connect tables without duplication, and if there is no name it should be just empty space.

What I want is to be:

```
| projectNo | proc_leader | proc_checker | proc_staff | 
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| 170002    | BARIKAN     |    BENNY     |   BOBBY    |
| 170002    |             |              |   CHRIS    |

proc_staff table:
| projectNo | process | proc_staff |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 170002    | CGI MOD |   BOBBY    |
| 170002    | CGI MOD |   CHRIS    |
```

Comment: You have 2 different rows in proc_staff. How you want show them?

Comment: @JoeTaras please see edit. I want to display them but without duplication

Comment: tell me more about PROC_STAFF table (post the strcuture)

Comment: @JoeTaras I added table structure. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange request, your data is tabellar, but... try this:

The subquery checks if doesn't exists staff before your actual staff element on the same project, you show information, instead you put to NULL (or if you want you can use '' as empty string)

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT pl.projectNo, 
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM proc_staff ps2
             WHERE ps2.project_no = ps.project_no
             AND ps2.proc_staff < ps.proc_staff) = 0
        THEN pl.proc_leader
        ELSE NULL
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM proc_staff ps2
             WHERE ps2.project_no = ps.project_no
             AND ps2.proc_staff < ps.proc_staff) = 0
        THEN pc.proc_checker
        ELSE NULL
    END,
    ps.proc_staff
FROM proc_leader pl
LEFT JOIN proc_checker pc
    ON pl.projectNo = pc.projectNo
LEFT JOIN proc_staff ps
    ON pl.projectNo = ps.projectNo
WHERE pl.projectNO="17010002" ORDER BY pl.projectNo
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have more than one row with the same projectNo in the proc_checker table or in the proc_staff.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might be useful is the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pl.projectNo, pl.proc_leader, pc.proc_checker, group_concat(ps.proc_staff SEPARATOR ', ') FROM proc_leader pl
LEFT JOIN proc_checker pc ON pl.projectNo=pc.projectNo
LEFT JOIN proc_staff ps ON pl.projectNo=ps.projectNo
WHERE pl.projectNO="17010002" ORDER BY pl.projectNo
```

The result should be something like this:

```
| projectNo | proc_leader | proc_checker | proc_staff       | 
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------------+
| 170002    | BARIKAN     |    BENNY     |   BOBBY, CHRIS   |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    pl.projectNo, 
    if(@i=0, p1.proc_leader, ''), 
    if(@i=0, pc.proc_checker, ''), 
    ps.proc_staff,
    @i:=@i+1
FROM (select @i:=0) as tmp, proc_leader pl
    LEFT JOIN proc_checker pc ON pl.projectNo=pc.projectNo
    LEFT JOIN proc_staff ps ON pl.projectNo=ps.projectNo
WHERE 
    pl.projectNO="17010002" 
ORDER BY 
    pl.projectNo
```